# Why do I get the same data with a different seed?

Tags: c++, std

For some reason, seed=0 and seed=1 give the same result, while I expect it to be different.

For different results everything works as expected, the problem arises only with 0 and 1 seeds.

Is it a bug or I don't understand something?

Code for reproduce. I tried it on gcc and g++ compilers.

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
  int32_t length = 100000;
  
  //first generated data 
  uint32_t seed1 = 0;
  std::default_random_engine generator1;
  generator1.seed(seed1);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int8_t> distribution1(0, 1);

  std::vector<int8_t> sequence1(length);

  for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    sequence1[i] = distribution1(generator1);
  }

  // second generated data
  uint32_t seed2 = 1;
  std::default_random_engine generator2;
  generator2.seed(seed2);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int8_t> distribution2(0, 1);

  std::vector<int8_t> sequence2(length);

  for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    sequence2[i] = distribution2(generator2);
  }


  //check if data the same
  bool sameData = true;
  for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (sequence1[i] != sequence2[i]) {
      sameData = false;
    }
  }
  
  std::cout << sameData; // true, but should be false
}
```

Comment: You should almost never set your own seed, unless you want deterministic sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "oddity" can likely be explained simply by noting that the PRNG you use, `std::default_random_engine`, is not very good.

Here is your code again, except now it compiles (was missing `#include <iostream>`) and using `std::mt19937` instead:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int32_t length = 100000;
  
  //first generated data 
  uint32_t seed1 = 0;
  std::mt19937 generator1;
  generator1.seed(seed1);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int8_t> distribution1(0, 1);

  std::vector<int8_t> sequence1(length);

  for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    sequence1[i] = distribution1(generator1);
  }

  // second generated data
  uint32_t seed2 = 1;
  std::mt19937 generator2;
  generator2.seed(seed2);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int8_t> distribution2(0, 1);

  std::vector<int8_t> sequence2(length);

  for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    sequence2[i] = distribution2(generator2);
  }


  //check if data the same
  bool sameData = true;
  for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (sequence1[i] != sequence2[i]) {
      sameData = false;
    }
  }
  
  std::cout << sameData; // true, but should be false
}
```

[Link to code](https://godbolt.org/z/6xP7obfvG)
Output:

```
0
```

Another small change was to make `#include <stdint.h>` => `#include <cstdint>` instead.

Per [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) page, if you `Ctrl+f` for `default_random_engine`, you'll see that it simply says it's implementation defined. This means the compiler writers get to do whatever they want.

This also means that for different compilers, it can behave differently and that would be allowed. I have no proof of this as I've never looked at any source code, but I believe that what at least gcc and clang do is implement a *very* simple, not all that random engine that barely suffices for rolling dice in a toy example. Once we move to using better engines that have strict requirements, you are *more likely* to see expected results. It's still not a guarantee.

This is because `std::seed_seq` is deterministic, and it's one of the steps that most PRNGs in `<random>` use when building their initial state.

Even `std::mt19937` must be used properly.

References:
https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/cpp-seeding-surprises.html
https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/05/seeding-stdmt19937-random-number-engine.html

Comment: `std::default_random_engine` is implementation-defined.  Depending on the standard library implementation, it's possible that `std::default_random_engine` and `std::mt19937` are actually the same thing.

Comment: Seems like it's indeed something undocumented on std::default_random_engine side.
Anyway,  std::mt19937 do the job.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a link to post about it being implementation defined. And while it *could be*, I believe what usually happens is that it's instead something extremely simple and not all that random. This will be going into the answer shortly.

Comment: @0x5453 In libstdc++ (usually used with gcc), they are not the same: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.h#L1607. It is "classic minimum standard linear congruential engine": https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.h#L1558.

Comment: @Saffer Please see the additional information and links in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do i get same data with diffirent seed

All seed values don't necessarily produce unique sequences.

In the standard library implementation that you use, the seeds that you chose happen to produce the same sequence with the given random engine. This is likely because 0 happens to be special for that particular engine.

In case you're using libstdc++, the behaviour that you observe is explained by [this](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.tcc#L114) implementation:

```
  template<typename _UIntType, _UIntType __a, _UIntType __c, _UIntType __m>
    void
    linear_congruential_engine<_UIntType, __a, __c, __m>::
    seed(result_type __s)
    {
      if ((__detail::__mod<_UIntType, __m>(__c) == 0)
          && (__detail::__mod<_UIntType, __m>(__s) == 0))  // <-- true if seed == 0
        _M_x = 1;     // <-- seed is set to 1!
      else
        _M_x = __detail::__mod<_UIntType, __m>(__s);
    }
```

---

Most trivial fix is to choose another pair of seeds, but here are some more generally useful advice:

- If you just want two different sequences, then use one generator and set the seed once. This way you don't accidentally get unfortunate pair of seeds, and you avoid the overhead of initialising the engine a second time.
- Unless you want repeatable sequences, it's better to use a variable source of seed, rather than hard coding it. A common strategy is to use the current time (in this case, I would pick the second seed for example by incrementing the first seed; getting current time again would likely result in the same seed due to granularity of the clock). While that doesn't solve all problems, it's unlikely to hit this anomalous case of 0.
- Unless you want repeatable sequences, you should use `std::random_device` to get a seed with (hopefully) good entropy.
- If you need good randomness properties, or if you need consistency across systems, then don't rely on `std::default_random_engine` which may for example be a LCG (bad randomness properties) and may vary between systems. Mersenne twister engine - provided by the standard library - is considered to have pretty good randomness and is a decent default choice unless you have a reason to choose another.

Answer (score 2):

libstdc++, which typically comes with gcc, defines `std::default_random_engine` as a typedef for `std::linear_congruential_engine<uint_fast32_t, 16807UL, 0UL, 2147483647UL>`. Source code links:

- https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.h#L1607
- https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.h#L1558

Note that this engine is so-called "classic Minimum Standard rand0 of Lewis, Goodman, and Miller". This engine is described in this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220420979_Random_Number_Generators_Good_Ones_Are_Hard_to_Find.

Inside, you may find its algorithm at page 1195. Note the following quote from that paper:

> This generator **must be initialized by assigning seed a value between 1 and 2147483646.** ... Unfortunately, for most systems **this version of Random is fatally flawed**.

Seed value 0 therefore even does not meet this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

A little debugging...

First let's notice that

```
template<typename _UIntType, _UIntType __a, _UIntType __c, _UIntType __m>
      class linear_congruential_engine { ...
```

Then

```
typedef linear_congruential_engine<uint_fast32_t, 16807UL, 0UL, 2147483647UL>
minstd_rand0;
typedef minstd_rand0 default_random_engine;
```

So we have a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with the parameter `C` set to zero. Now...

```
   |114       template<typename _UIntType, _UIntType __a, _UIntType __c, _UIntType __m>                                                           │
   │115         void                                                                                                                              │
   │116         linear_congruential_engine<_UIntType, __a, __c, __m>::                                                                            │
   │117         seed(result_type __s)                                                                                                             │
   │118         {                                                                                                                                 │
   │119           if ((__detail::__mod<_UIntType, __m>(__c) == 0)                                                                                 │
   │120               && (__detail::__mod<_UIntType, __m>(__s) == 0))                                                                             │
  >│121             _M_x = 1;                                                                                                                     │
   │122           else                                                                                                                            │
   │123             _M_x = __detail::__mod<_UIntType, __m>(__s);                                                                                  │
   │124         }                                                                                                                                ​
```

So the implementation refuses to seed with 0, and seeds with 1 instead. And a good thing too, because a zero seed simply wouldn't work when C==0. It will produce a constant stream of zeros (change `_M_x` in the debugger and see... or just look at the formula).

It is not guaranteed that different values of seed result in different pseudo-random sequences.